# Sql-Agent not starting on an Ubuntu SQL Server docker container in an azure container

Tags: sql-server, docker, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I am using docker to deploy an linux sql-server to azure.

And I cannot get the Sql-Server agent to run on a container instance on Ubuntu in azure. The Sql-Server starts fine but not the Sql-Agent. I have tried with different versions of SQL-Server.

Locally it works fine with this example:

```
docker run -d -p 15789:1433 `
--env ACCEPT_EULA=Y `
--env SA_PASSWORD=Testing1122 `
--env MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=True `
--name testcontainer `
mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-GDR1-ubuntu-16.04
```

[image]

But when adding the same image to azure container registry and then to an container instance it is not working:

[image]

In the log for the container I can see the following error which I am not sure if it is correlated to that the agent is not starting:

```
2020-10-20 14:36:24.91 spid35s     Error: 39002, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2020-10-20 14:36:24.91 spid35s     SQL failed to boot extensibility for error code 0x80070005.
2020-10-20 14:36:24.91 spid35s     InitializeXdbPkgLauncher failed. ErrorCode: 0x80004005.
```

Someone that knows why this isnt working or how it can be fixed to be able to run it in an azure container instance?

Comment: The plan was to use the agent to do scheduled backups, but for now (and maybe also later) I will use this service for scheduled backups: https://sqlbackupandftp.com/ which seems nice to have the backups in dropbox for example.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue and we found out that this is due to a limitation that exists in azure container instances: sql agent can't be enabled (looks enabled but in reality it isn't) when the instance name is greater than 15 characters long. Unfortunately, instance names are auto-assigned by the Kubernetes cluster at container creation time and you have no control over that. Vote for this idea if you would like the issue to be addressed (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances/suggestions/42509800-support-setting-of-hostname).

Comment: as absurd as this is, it worked on first try. I'd upvote 10 times if I could.

Comment: (in my case I was able to assign a shorter hostname, that's what I mean with "it worked on first try". upvoted on the azure feedback anyways)

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, the image `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-GDR1-ubuntu-16.04` has the same error both in local and the Azure Container Instance. The [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/122031/sql-server-2019-linux-docker-bug.html) shows here that it's a bug in SQL Server 2019. And I try to use the image `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU21-ubuntu-16.04` and there is no problem. If you do not mind, try it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to use the 2017 but unfortunately with the same results for my azure container instance. I dont understand why it works when i run it locally though. Not sure if it can have something to do with the issue described here: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/503

Comment: @Sgedda How do you test it the things go well?

Comment: I was running the docker container locally as command above on windows, that worked fine for me even with 2019. What about you? @Charles Xu

Comment: @Sgedda The image 2019 also does not work well in my local windows. It gives the same error. I guess there is something missed in my windows.

Comment: Thats weird, I will try on a different machine and let you know the results.