# How enable SQL Server Agent in docker container existing

Tags: sql-server, docker, sql-server-agent

I have a running SQL Server image on Docker, however I need to enable SQL Server Agent to run some jobs, but I have not succeeded. The main problem is that the container has quite a few databases and settings that need to be maintained. The command "docker run -e" MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED = true ... "" is not useful to me because it creates a new container and I would lose the current configuration.

I used the following commands that allowed to enable the interface, but when running the job I get an error that SQL Server Agent is not enabled

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
reconfigure
exec sp_configure 'Agent XPs',1
reconfigure
```

The error generated when executing the job is the following

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
> SQLServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot be notified of this action. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 22022)

I tried to start the SQL Server Agent with the command `EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'START ', N'SQLServerAGENT'`, but it generates another error

> StartService() returned error 1053, 'The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.'

The question would be, how can I enable the SQL Server Agent in the container that is already running to be able to schedule jobs

Comment: Creating a new container is the only way to patch SQL Server.  So you should do that here too.

Comment: StartService error 1053 is a Windows service control manager error. Are you sure you're connected to the SQL Server inside the Docker container?

Answer (score 26):

If you've already created a Docker container with something like SQL Server 2019 Developer edition:

```sh
$ docker run -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e MSSQL_PID=Developer -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=YourStrongPassw0rd -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
57301203bac57455a118e0dbe6ff392cb19313375c134050e6ecd77414555e7e
```

With reference to [Configure SQL Server on Linux with the mssql-conf tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf?view=sql-server-ver15#agent), get a root shell in the container:

```sh
$ docker exec -it --user root 57301203bac5 bash
```

Then enable SQL Agent in the configuration file and restart the SQL Server service:

```sh
root@57301203bac5:/# /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set sqlagent.enabled true
SQL Server needs to be restarted in order to apply this setting. Please run
'systemctl restart mssql-server.service'.

root@57301203bac5:/# systemctl restart mssql-server.service
```

If you get an error message such as `systemctl: command not found` then just stop and start the container for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 11):

From outside the container go into terminal by doing the following:

```
sudo docker exec -it --user root sql1 "bash"
```

The password will not be of the container.

Next elevate yourself to superuser:

```
su -
```

Next enable sqlagent by changing the configuration file:

```
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set sqlagent.enabled true
```

Now exit the container by typing exit once to logout from root and next to exit from the container

```
exit
exit
```

Finally restart the the docker container that has your microsoft sql server instance running

(in this case tagged sql1)

```
docker restart sql1
```

N.B. Within SQL Management Studio you need to right click the SQL Server Agent Icon and refresh to verify it is up.

[image: SQL SERVER AGENT]

Note you no longer have to do this if you enabled SQL server agent with the flag when initialising the container:

```
docker run -d -p 1433:1433 --env ACCEPT_EULA=Y --env SA_PASSWORD='MYSUP3RS@!3' --env MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=True --name sql1 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-GDR1-ubuntu-16.04
```

Comment: "su" DO asks for an unknown password.

Comment: Yeah this will be the "root" password for the host.

Comment: I followed this to the point. All steps and also the alternative with the MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED in the compose script environment values list. In SMSS, the agent icon shows a microscopic half-pixel-sized green spot for which to see I needed stronger glasses, but no dice. agent service does not start. attempting to start a job gives 22022 SQLServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot... Nothing of relevance in the container log.

Comment: resolution: the instance name (host name) may not be longer than 15 characters. who'd've thunk. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66971139/1132334

Comment: [This](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/599#issuecomment-673707961) has helped me to log into the running SQL Qerver container as the root user and thus circumvent the need to enter a password for it.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using Docker Compose, it's much easier to just add a flag to the yaml environment:

```
environment:
  MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED: true
```

Then just down and up the container again.

[More info at Microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-environment-variables?view=sql-server-ver16)

Credit goes to Mickeybyte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76182745