# Failed to set sqlagent.enabled in docker container: SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, docker

I installed SQL Server 2019 Docker container by referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-restore-backup-in-sql-server-container?view=sql-server-linux-ver15. After the installation, I need to enable change data capture, so I tried to set sqlagent enabled in the container with the command:

```
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf 
set sqlagent.enabled true
```

But I got a warning:

```
> Warning: could not create log file for mssql-conf at /var/opt/mssql/log/mssql-conf/mssql-conf.log.     
> This program must be run as superuser or as a user with membership in the SQL Server.
```

And when I opened the config file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/mssql.conf`, I couldn't find the relative config.

> # mssql libs
> /opt/mssql/lib

When I entered *whoami* , the result is

> mssql

When I entered *top* , the result is

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
9 mssql     20   0   10.0g 680964  20764 S  17.3   8.5  26:38.68 sqlservr                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
1 mssql     20   0   57016   8516   1308 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.87 sqlservr
```

I'm wondering why *sqlsgent.enabled* ended with the warning.

Comment: `mssql` user is a lesser-privileged account and doesn't have permissions to modify the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/mssql.conf` file. Did you `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set sqlagent.enabled true` as per [Enable SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf#agent)? Configuring an image from a Dockerfile you'd `USER root` `RUN /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set sqlagent.enabled true` and `USER mssql` to revert to the normal account.

Comment: Your comment is really helpful, but why not record as an answer so that I can star it? With your help, I solved the problem following these steps:  1. enter the container on root: `docker exec -it -u root sql1 bash`  2. use `apt-get` to install `sudo` and `vim` 3. change user mssql's password: `passwd mssql` 4. enable user mssql  to use sudo: `visudo` 5. reentry the container on mssql: `docker exec -it sql1 bash` 6.  `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set sqlagent.enabled true` 7. quit the container and restart the container: `docker restart sql` 8. got it, then I can continue to use cdc ^_^

Comment: Because mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest is an official image, I'd better not edit the Dockerfile and rebuild the image. Am I right?

Comment: You don't need to edit MSFT's Dockerfile but you can create your own Dockerfile that builds on top of that image. That's a normal thing to do in Docker circles because you almost always need to customize images in some way for a particular application. There are many examples of this on learn.microsoft.com as well, including [Build and run non-root SQL Server 2017 containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-security#buildnonrootcontainer). I'd normally do it as part of a Docker composition, though, rather than standalone Dockerfiles.

Answer (score 0):

There's an environment variable you can set to enable the SQL Agent in a container:
MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED = true

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-environment-variables?view=sql-server-ver16

Much easier than installing sudo in your container just to enable it...